# Git commit ignores changes to certain subfolders. Any Suggestions on how to rectify the issue?

Tags: git, github, addition

I have been using Github for a year, but I have mostly been using the basic functionality. I still consider myself a newbie. I have an Arduino directory configured as a github repository. This directory, as shown below has a number of project folders within it. It also as a workspace that in itself has a number of projects. When using the commands below, I have no trouble adding, committing, and pushing the changes. Any changes made to the files or folders within directory levels 1 and 2 are added, committed, and pushed effectively. However, up to directory level 3 only changes to the ".settings" folder is added. The highlighted folders (shown by *****) are never added or uploaded to the master branch. Any changes to the highlighted folders are ignored by "git add ." command. Any ideas as to why this is happening would be appreciated.

Things I have tried to determine why the highlighted folders are ignored:

1. If I move the "Release" folder up one directory (to level 2), the "git add ." command collects all changes and git commit/push uploads them.
2. I saw a post about a ".gitignore" file possibly listing file or folders to be ignored. I could not locate this file if it exists in my repo, the Git installation directory or the user directory.

Operating System: Windows 10 Home
Git Version: 2.21.0.windows.1
Terminal: Git-bash

Commands: git add .; git commit -m "first commit"; git push

Repo: Git_Arduino

[Git_Arduino Repo Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCZcx.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It looks like your screen capture is that of a terminal (or a text file), it is better to paste the text in your question than linking an image.

Comment: I thought to include the text in line with the post, however, I was not able to keep the formatting as seen in the attached image. Each time I listed the text in the directory level format shown, it got converted into a single line of text. I will try again in my next post. Thanks!

Comment: use "```" (three backquotes) to start/end a `<pre>` block in a StackOverflow post. You can also inline `code blocks` by surrounding them with a single backquote "`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.gitignore` file can be placed at any level in the hierarchy :

- at the root of `Git_Arduino/`
- in `Git_Arduino/SloeberWorspace/`
- in `Git_Arduino/SloeberWorspace/ProjectA/`

From the root of your repo, you can check :

```
ls .gitignore
ls SloeberWorspace/.gitignore
ls SloeberWorspace/ProjectA/.gitignore
```

You can also use a standard tool like `find` :

```
# from your repo's root directory :
find . -name .gitignore
```

Comment: Thanks @LeGEC. I was able to find the .gitignore within each Git_Arduino/SloeberWorspace/ProjectX/ folder. I was able to edit and then add/commit/push changes to the repository. I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3):

Execute `git check-ignore -v` in folder to detect this folder was ignored by which ignore setting.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ran the command under several folders and it resulted in a "" (empty string) output. However, I was able to resolve the issue by finding the .gitignore file within the associated folders.